# how to make text center and another text on right side of panel body

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a panel body and in that I want a heading to be centered and a some more text to be right.

How can I do?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading panel_bg  text-center"><span>Interests</span> <div class="no_of_category_selected">02/18</div></div>
</div>
```

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: please acknowledge by upvoting the answers below that helped you in solving the question now that you have sufficient reputation for it... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly you can do it with some custom styling as there is no such styling exists in `bootstrap.css` for this:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.panel-heading {
  padding-right: 120px;
  padding-left: 120px;
  position: relative;
}
.more-text {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  right: 15px;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading panel_bg  text-center">
    <span>Interests</span>
    <span class="more-text text-right">02/18</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```css
.content{
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading panel_bg">
    <div class="text-center">
      <span>Interests</span> 
      <div class="no_of_category_selected pull-right">02/18</div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-right content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis ipsum velit eum magnam rerum nobis tempora soluta est impedit corporis iste odio adipisci sint similique sed, repudiandae, unde quisquam, possimus. </p>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want `02/18` to be inline with Interests to the right side.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.panel-heading panel_bg  text-center 
{
   background-color: #999999;
   height: 50px;
   width: 24.5%;
}
.no_of_category_selected 
{
   display:block;
   width:100px;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading panel_bg  text-center"><span>Interests</span> <div class="no_of_category_selected">02/18</div></div>
</div>
```